# Port not accessible even after being exposed. Connection refused

Tags: docker

we created a docker container like this:

```
docker container create \
    --name orderer \
    --network dscsa_net \
    --workdir $WORK_DIR \
    --expose=7050 \
    hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.3.0 ./start-orderer.sh
```

but are unable to connect to port 7050 on the container.

```
root@dcee7e74266f:/home# nc -vz 10.0.0.194 7050
nc: connect to 10.0.0.194 port 7050 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

we are able to ping the container:

```
root@dcee7e74266f:/home# ping 10.0.0.194
PING 10.0.0.194 (10.0.0.194) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.194: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.810 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.194: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.30 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.194: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.668 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.194: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=1.10 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.194: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.631 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.194 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.631/0.902/1.301/0.261 ms
```

and also see a process listening on port 7050 on the container:

```
root@9756199efefa:/home# netstat -tuplen
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          10097930    7/orderer       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:34865        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          10097705    -               
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:51385        0.0.0.0:*                           0          10097704    -
```

what is going on here? how can we fix this?

EDIT: we are on a overlay network. The publish flag suggested in the answer is n/a as we are doing container to container communication. Anyway we tried it and it doesn't work.

There is one thing we have noticed which is if we run:

```
docker network inspect <our-network-name>
```

Among other things, it prints out a `containers` section but in that section only the containers on the host from which `docker network inspect` is executed are listed. The containers hosted on other nodes are not listed (also mentioned [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24186)).

we verified that if we run:

```
docker node ls
```

all the nodes are part of the swarm.

It seems other people have also run into this issue e.g., [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/28795) but what is the solution?

**Note:** we are able to connect to another container running a different service exposed on port 7054. This container was created without even using the `expose` flag.

```
root@dcee7e74266f:/home# nc -zv 10.0.0.164 7054
Connection to 10.0.0.164 7054 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

Did further debugging with tcpdump and output of tcpdump is identical to the output when someone tries to connect to a port on which no process is listening. But as shown earlier netstat shows a process that is listening and we can connect to the process from localhost.

Output of tcpdump:

```
root@dcee7e74266f:/test# tcpdump -s0 host 10.0.0.195 
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
23:44:45.978583 IP dcee7e74266f.52148 > orderer.dscsa_net.7050: Flags [S], seq 3845506108, win 28200, options [mss 1410,sackOK,TS val 4203049443 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:44:45.979324 IP orderer.dscsa_net.7050 > dcee7e74266f.52148: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 3845506109, win 0, length 0
```

The R flag tells client to reset the connection.

Output of traceroute:

```
root@dcee7e74266f:/test# traceroute 10.0.0.195     
traceroute to 10.0.0.195 (10.0.0.195), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  orderer.dscsa_net (10.0.0.195)  1.008 ms  0.900 ms  0.872 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue thanks to [1](https://askubuntu.com/a/166106/393311). The server listening to `127.0.0.1` was the problem. Once we changed the listening address to `0.0.0.0` (shows as `:::` in `netstat` output below), we are able to connect to the server:

```
root@e9766a94d102:/home# netstat -tuplen          
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:37641        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          12821468    -               
tcp6       0      0 :::7050                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          12821696    7/orderer       
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:51855        0.0.0.0:*                           0          12821467    -
```

there is no need for either `expose` or `publish` flags. note to self: wasted 1.5 days on this.

Answer (score 5):

Expose only sets metadata on the image or container, it does not make the port externally accessible. The option you are looking for is publish:

```
docker container create \
    --name orderer \
    --network dscsa_net \
    --workdir $WORK_DIR \
    --publish=7050:7050 \
    hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.3.0 ./start-orderer.sh
```