# Ports not being published

Tags: docker, go

I have this config (using the `go-dockerclient` https://github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient) for a container but it only opens the tcp port when running the container:

```
...
StartConfig: docker.HostConfig{
    PortBindings: map[docker.Port][]docker.PortBinding{
        "53/tcp": {{HostIP: "0.0.0.0", HostPort: "1053"}},
        "53/udp": {{HostIP: "0.0.0.0", HostPort: "1053"}},
    },
```

I tried in every possible way without luck. When I run the container using the cmd it works as expected:

```
docker run -d \
    -p 0.0.0.0:1053:53/udp \
    -p 0.0.0.0:1053:53/tcp ...
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong here?

Container inspect output:

```
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "4bdea4ccda50aaf8a3117098fdd2073943af43e8d991ddd7a0be425c5599dfbd",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "53/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "1053"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/4bdea4ccda50",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "1796f8bda73d13d354bcd8bafaf6c1f4ff1491582c3985f6b653ccc6b2226e01",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": null,
                "NetworkID": "fb85e54ede4e18ae48e4c889d169d2d4cd8b2087a8c9691e094a431cb6a7eb43",
                "EndpointID": "1796f8bda73d13d354bcd8bafaf6c1f4ff1491582c3985f6b653ccc6b2226e01",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker: Port not accessible even after being exposed. Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55055383/docker-port-not-accessible-even-after-being-exposed-connection-refused)

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea can you share the result of a running container with the go client ?

Comment: Nope. ports are up when the container is started via cmd. It's just the go client that refuses to set it up properly.

Comment: @Mostafa Hussein I updated the question to include inspect output.

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea your current inspect output seems to be good. based on your question i assume this is after running `docker run` I am looking for the result after running the go script

Comment: @Mostafa Hussein the udp port is not responding. Here's a healthy inspect when the container is executed via cmd: https://gist.github.com/ciokan/f574a769315fc7c8bf0bc8ef1c374999 (the above result is after running the go client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the following example which worked as expected for me, the example as shown below:

The docker image link: https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-bind

> Maybe the issue is related with the image that you have?

```go
package main

import (
    docker "github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient"
)

func main() {
    endpoint := "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    client, err := docker.NewClient(endpoint)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    container, err := client.CreateContainer(docker.CreateContainerOptions{
        Name:   "my-container",
        Config: &docker.Config{Image: "sameersbn/bind:9.11.3-20190113"},
            HostConfig: &docker.HostConfig{
            PortBindings: map[docker.Port][]docker.PortBinding{
                "53/tcp": {{HostIP: "0.0.0.0", HostPort: "1053"}},
                "53/udp": {{HostIP: "0.0.0.0", HostPort: "1053"}},
            },
        },
    },
    )
    client.StartContainer(container.ID, nil)
}
```

Docker inspect results:

```
"Ports": {
  "10000/tcp": null,
  "53/tcp": [
    {
      "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
      "HostPort": "1053"
    }
  ],
  "53/udp": [
    {
      "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
      "HostPort": "1053"
    }
  ]
},
```

Make sure that you have this in your Dockerfile as by default `EXPOSE` assumes `TCP` as described in [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose):

```
EXPOSE 53/udp 53/tcp
```

Comment: Interesting. Can you also post the dockerfile?

Comment: I have added the image url

Comment: We might be on to something. Their expose: `EXPOSE 53/udp 53/tcp 10000/tcp`. My expose: `EXPOSE 53`

Comment: The docs says: By default, EXPOSE assumes TCP. Maybe that is the reason indeed

Comment: I spent hours on this:
`docker run` does not require port to be exposed. However using Docker Engine API and`HostConfig.PortBindings` when creating the container EXPOSE seems to be important. I was simply trying to publish both ports 3000 and 443, and I've only had `EXPOSE 3000`. 
`docker run -p 443:443 -p 3000:3000 ...` just worked, and when creating the container using API - no luck until I added `EXPOSE 443` as well.